# Count object from Firebase GET that meet several conditions

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-realtime-database

I have a project to implement Golang integration with Firebase. The goal sounds pretty simple: I want to count how many objects in database that meet the condition (for this example if the
    location 
is in POOL XYZ and 
    time_out 
is 0) and return it with format like this:

```
pool XYZ,n
```

Where poolXYZ is from the Location and n is number(s) of the objects

This is my JSON Firebase structure example (for testing)

```
"vehicles" : {
    "VB201" : {
      "register" : "VB201",
      "police_number" : "",
      "position" : {
        "content" : {
          "location" : "POOL XYZ",
          "stat" : 0,
          "time_in" : 1555331615429,
          "time_out" : 0,
          "username" : "POOL XYZ1"
        }
      },
      "trips" : {
        "content" : {
          "accept" : "POOL XYZ",
          "stat" : 1,
          "status" : 0,
          "time_stop" : 1555331615429,
          "username" : "POOL XYZ1"
        }
      }
    }
      }
 }
```

The things that i want to do is get the "register" of the vehicle, VB201, cause it meet the condition (POOL XYZ and time_out 0). There're several objects like this and has same JSON structure. SO the result might be

```
POOL XYZ, 1
```

Comment: Querying your data in this fashion is going to be expensive resource-wise as your entire "vehicles" tree will have to be downloaded to run the query (in addition to be a security problem). Instead, I would suggest implementing a shallow index such as `{ "vehiclesByPool": { "POOL XYZ": { "VB201": 0 /* time_out value */, "VB202": 1555331615429 }, "POOL ABC": { "VB203": 0 } } }` which will improve performance significantly.

Comment: Thank you sir, but actually this database is implemented (or maybe i don't know) without shallow index, and I don't have right to implemented it, due the restriction of my job task. Does someone know the alternatives about it? Btw, i have change the strategy to make the query hard-coded on server only, so the user only access the result without querying in client side.

Comment: Honestly, take it to your supervisor and get the rights to implement it. [Denormalizing data is normal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s&index=6) for NoSQL databases like the Firebase RTDB. Adding an index to an existing project is not all too difficult and will save time and money.

Comment: But one thing that bother me, if i do de-normalization on my database, it will affect the entire database (based from what i read from the doc and watch Firebase for SQL programmer video). But my database behavior is update dynamically; it will add new object due in the real case there's always new vehicle enter and wait at the place. For query reason, i need to denormalizing the data, but i'm affraid about client side about time consumption, due the data must served immediately in client side when client need it.